# findcontrol in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to use `FindControl` to find the value of the `HiddenField` i.e `hfBlogID`. I want to find the value on a `ButtonClick`

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvArticle" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder">
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfBlogID" Value='<%#Eval("BlogID")%>' runat="server" />
        <p>
            <%#Eval("BlogTitle")%></p>
        <p>
            <%#Eval("BlogDetails")%></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to determine the correct *row index* you should place your button inside of your `ListView.ItemTemplate` and handle the `ListView.ItemCommand` event.

In order to implement this approach you would have to change your code as follows:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvArticle" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lv_ItemCommand">
..
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfBlogID" Value='<%#Eval("BlogID")%>' runat="server" />
        <p>
            <%#Eval("BlogTitle")%></p>
        <p>
            <%#Eval("BlogDetails")%></p>
        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="find" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("yourIDField") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
...
```

In code behind:

```
protected void lv_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "find":
            var hidden = e.Item.FindControl("your hidden id") as HiddenField;
            break;
    }
}
```

If your button **is not inside your ListView**, then you would need a way to identify the row you want to extract the hidden value from.

For example, if you allow to select a row in your `ListView` then you could get the hidden value from the selected row as follows:

```
protected void find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hidden = this.lv.Items[this.lv.SelectedIndex].FindControl("your hidden ID") as HiddenField;
}
```

Comment: My button is not inside my `ListView` ...i cannot get the selected index as nothing is being selected...but there is only one row at a time ...so i can always go for the first row..how would i do that??

Comment: If there's only one row then use this: `var hidden = this.lvArticle.Items[0].FindControl("your hidden ID") as HiddenField;`

Comment: i get this exception `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: Then it means your list view is empty mate. Are you sure it **contains one row**?

Comment: This is not the typical way to use a `ListView`, if you want to execute a command you **should place the button inside the `ItemTemplate`** otherwise (like in your case), you should be completley sure that your `ListView` contains an item in the position you are trying to access it. You could try adding a conditional though, but again this is not the way to go. Add `if (this.lv.Items.Count > 0) ...`

Comment: Thanks friend :) You helped a lot...you are right..`ListView` was empty...now its working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use if button is in your listview

```
var control = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfBlogID");
```

or if button is not in your listvew

```
 var contorl = (HiddenField)this.lvArticle.Items[this.lvArticle.SelectedIndex].FindControl("hfBlogID");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the button is in the same item template then use ItemCommand event handler and in that handler you can fetch the hidden field directly.

If the button is outside of list view then you need to get the index of item whose hidden field'd value you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can access the hidden field for each item:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  foreach(ListViewDataItem item in lvArticle.Items)
   {
     HiddenField hf=(HiddenField)item.FindControl("hfBlogID");
   }

}
```

if you have index of item already then you can get it directly like this

```
 HiddenField hf=(HiddenField)lvArticle.Items[index].FindControl("hfBlogID");
```

Hope this will help..